# How to clear Module database in MarkLogic

Tags: gradle, marklogic, ml-gradle

What is the gradle task to clear all modules in a MarkLogic database?

I have tried `mlClearDatabase`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`mlClearDatabase` will clear the **content** database.

The task that you are looking for to clear the **modules** database is:

[`mlClearModulesDatabase`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Task-reference#modules) - if the application exists, clear its modules database; otherwise do nothing

If you are clearing the modules in order to ensure that you are deploying to a fresh modules database, then you might want to use [`mlReloadModules`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Common-tasks#reload-modules), which will invoke `mlClearModules` and then `mlLoadModules`.

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Task-reference#modules

Answer (score 0):

`mlClearModulesDatabase`

> gradle doesn't gurantee complete Modules database cleanup if other App server has dependency on that Modules database

`mlClearDatabase -Pdatabase={db-name} -Pconfirm=true`

> gradle will clear the said database in force mode, for that reason, -Pconfirm=true is used. If other App servers have dependency on the cleared Modules database, your application will fail.

It is very true that `mlReloadModules` is the right way to deploy/redeploy modules.